# Query linq with subquery returning selected fields and sorted in both queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two tables:

**Cars**

- carId (int) primary
- carName (varchar)
- carRegisterDate (date)

**Photos**

- photoId     (int)
- photoCarId  (int)      //foreign key from cardId in Cars
- photoSortId (int)      //sort photos by int value
- photoIsMain (bool)     //determines if it's main photo
- photoName   (varchar)

My goal is:

1. Perform a query in Cars querying n records
2. Perform a subquery on photos table that has a foreign key linked to cars table. In this query I need:

   - sort by photoSortId field
   - get photoName in a separate field which record has the field photoIsMain == true
   - count total photos items

Currently I'm using a query in the cars table returning a collection and looping through it, and for each car item I create a query in the photo table, ordering through the photosSortId field and checking if the photoIsMain field is true.

I would be able to get such data, sort fields only using linq? Would I get a faster performance if I did so?

Currently I do something like:

```
public class ListCars
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CarRegisterDate { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListPhotos { get; set; }
    public string MainPhoto { get; set; }
    public int CarTotal { get; set; }
}

// First - query cars
var cars = await(from c in _db.Cars)
    select new ListCars
    {
     CarId = c.carId
     CarName = c.carName
     CarRegisterDate = c.carRegisterDate
    })
    .AsNoTracking().Take(9)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CarRegisterDate)
    .ToListAsync();

// Loop foreach car
foreach (var carItem in cars)
{
    //query photos
    var photos = await(from p in _db.Photos
                       where p.photoCarId == carItem.CarId
                       orderby p.photoSortId
                       select new { p.photoName, p.photoIsMain }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

    //List for get
    cars.ListPhotos = new List<string>();

    foreach (var photoItem in photos)
    {
        //Count photos items
        carItem.CarTotal++;

        //check if is main
        if (photoItem.photoIsMain)
        {
            carItem.MainPhoto = p.photoName;
        }

        //Add photoName to list
        cars.ListPhotos.Add(p.photoName);
    }
}
```

Is there a more appropriate approach?

Comment: As with many things people do nowadays you are turning a simple join query into procedural work. Will be far more efficient if you can submit the whole query in one go. Someone with more linq knowledge will have to tell you how though.

Comment: Start with `_db.Cars.Include(c => c.Photos)`.